# R, Ruby, MySQL Google Earth Network links... how do I get these working?

Tags: r, http, kml

Wonder if anyone could give me some tips on how to get something working. Even if it's a completely different way than I'm currently trying.

I'm looking into displaying a lot of data on google earth, so I've been directed towards using region based network links to cut down the amount of information being loaded into google earth.

I use R for most of my data analysis/selection so would like if I could select the data to be shown with R instead of learning a new language. I have R working with a MySQL database.

My understanding is that I can set up a network link based on regions in a KML file, so say when you zoom in on paris, it activates the link corresponding to paris. But seemingly it's possible to set up the network link to run a script via http request... this is the bit i'm having trouble with.

Ideally I would like to have the network link calling an R script which then prints out the relevant kml and displays the data. Is this possible?

It seems other languages are more suited to this, such as Ruby/PHP/Perl/Python but I seem to be getting out of my depth getting these to work (I have a *very* small bit of ruby).

Is there any way to achieve this in R or to do most of the work in R but have the link in one of these other languages? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://cran.r-project.org/, you *should*[1] be able to get an R script to output KML.

The key will be in identifying a key, a hash or some other data which the parent page can contain so as to link down into child pages with more detail. It is a lot easier for a parent KML document to be able to link to child documents based on keys or hashes which are known at "parent creation" time rather than trying something such as "here's my screen viewport - give me something suitable".

I have found the following link to be somewhat helpful: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/regions#regionbasednl - in your case you will want to change the 6th-last link from `<href>romaniaRegion.kml</href>` to something like `http://my.server/cgi-bin/R/foo.kml?key=abc`.

Note that you need to ensure the script sets appropriate headers, is quick and that your KML is correct - debugging KML issues (especially if it's a large file) is tedious.

[1] Disclaimer: I have not tried this and have no R experience.